# react-native redux-toolkit: a non-serializable value was detected in the state, but my object is serializable

Tags: typescript, react-native, redux, redux-thunk, redux-toolkit

I just migrated my old-school `react-native` with `redux` App to the modern `redux-toolkit` and now I have this error:

```
A non-serializable value was detected in the state, in the path: `currentUserSessionData.data`. Value:, CurrentUserSessionData {
  "isOnboardingDone": false,
}, 
Take a look at the reducer(s) handling this action type: currentUserSessionDataSlice/get/pending.
```

Which is very strange because the object `CurrentUserSessionData` is so simple:

```
class CurrentUserSessionData {
    isOnboardingDone: boolean = false;
}

export default CurrentUserSessionData;
```

I really think **it is serializable**!

Also, isn't it strange that the error writes: "Value:**comma** CurrentUserSessionData"? That comma after **:** seems strange, and I never defined the `pending` **extra reducer**.

---

I thought I made a mistake in the state or store definitions, I read and read the documentation a lot of times but I don't find the problem!

The **slice:**

```
import {createAsyncThunk, createSlice} from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import * as CurrentUserSessionDataRepository from '../services/CurrentUserSessionDataRepository';
import CurrentUserSessionData from "../models/CurrentUserSessionData";

export const currentUserSessionDataSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'currentUserSessionDataSlice',
    initialState: {
        data: new CurrentUserSessionData(),
    },
    reducers: {},
    extraReducers: build => {

        build.addCase(currentUserSessionDataGetAsync.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
            state.data = action.payload;
        });

    },
});

export const currentUserSessionDataGetAsync = createAsyncThunk(
    "currentUserSessionDataSlice/get",
    async () => {
        return await CurrentUserSessionDataRepository.getCurrentUserSessionData();
    }
)
```

---

The data **repository**:

```
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
import * as Logger from "./Logger";
import CurrentUserSessionData from "../models/CurrentUserSessionData";

const asyncStorageCurrentUserSessionDataKey: string = "currentUserSessionData";

export const getCurrentUserSessionData = async (): Promise<CurrentUserSessionData> =>
{

    Logger.logDebug('getCurrentUserSessionData');
    const sessionDataRaw = await AsyncStorage.getItem(asyncStorageCurrentUserSessionDataKey);

    if (sessionDataRaw) {
        return JSON.parse(sessionDataRaw) as CurrentUserSessionData;
    }

    return {
        isOnboardingDone: false
    };

};
```

---

The **store**:

```
import {configureStore} from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import {combineReducers} from "redux";
import {currentUserSessionDataSlice} from "./currentUserSessionDataSlice";
import {TypedUseSelectorHook, useDispatch, useSelector} from "react-redux";

const appStateStore = configureStore({
    reducer: combineReducers({
        currentUserSessionData: currentUserSessionDataSlice.reducer,
        // ....
    })
});

export default appStateStore;
export type IRootState = ReturnType<typeof appStateStore.getState>;
export type IAppDispatch = typeof appStateStore.dispatch;
export const useAppDispatch = () => useDispatch<IAppDispatch>();
export const useAppSelector: TypedUseSelectorHook<IRootState> = useSelector;
```

---

How I **dispatch**:

```
import {useAppDispatch} from "./appStateStore/appStateStore";
// ...
const dispatch = useAppDispatch();
await dispatch(currentUserSessionDataGetAsync());
// ...
```

---

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the problem is that it's an actual `class`.  Class instances are not fully serializable, and you effectively never need to use an actual class when writing a React+Redux app.  Just make that a plain JS object instead.

In other words, instead of this:

```
    initialState: {
        data: new CurrentUserSessionData(),
    },
```

Just do:

```
    initialState: {
        data: {isOnboardingDone: false}
    },
```

Also, as a side note, you don't have to call `combineReducers` yourself - `configureStore` can do it for you.

Comment: Oops, I didn't know that! I converted everything to interfaces and its working. Is Date serializable? Where can I find the list of non serializable types? Thanks.

Comment: Dates are also not entirely serializable.  Effectively, only plain JS objects, arrays, and primitives (booleans, strings, numbers) are 100% serializable.